# Morphia : Querying a mongo collection having a @reference to another collection taking time

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have two mongo collections :

```
public class TransactionDetails {
    private String TYPE="NA";
    private Long TransactionDateInLong;
    @Reference
    List<AccountingTransaction> accountingTransactionList;
}
```

And

```
public class AccountingTransaction{
//Fields here.
}
```

I am trying to query "TransactionDetails" collection using morphia framework to fetch the referenced "AccountingTransaction".

Here is the method for morphia query :

```
public List<TransactionDetails> getTransactions(Long fromDateInLong, Long endDateInLong) {
        Query<TransactionDetails> query = createQuery();

        query.and(
                query.criteria("TransactionDateInLong").lessThanOrEq(endDateInLong),
                query.criteria("TransactionDateInLong").greaterThanOrEq(fromDateInLong)
        );

       query.and(
               query.criteria("TYPE").equal("Income")
        );

        return query.retrievedFields(true, "accountingTransactionList").asList();
    }
```

Indexes are created for "TransactionDateInLong" and "TYPE" fields :

```
db.getCollection('TransactionDetails').createIndex({"TransactionDateInLong" : 1.0});
db.getCollection('TransactionDetails').createIndex({"TYPE" : "text"});
```

Query is taking a lot of time, with the indexes created.

Getting the exception as "Cursor not found on the server".

Any improvements? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have referenced a lot of `AccountingTransaction` this will be a very costly query. `@Reference` is only a driver feature, so what happens in the background:

- You query `TransactionDetails`, transmit it to your application, and parse it.
- When the driver finds an element in the `@Reference` it will run a query for every single element to fetch that element (each one doing another round trip between your application and MongoDB).
- It will combine `TransactionDetails` and `AccountingTransaction` in your application.

So if your query matches 100 `TransactionDetails` and each one has 10 `AccountingTransaction` you will run 1 + 100 * 10 queries in total.

I think it does exactly the same thing behind the scenes, but I find a query like this much more readable (everything is `and` connected by default:

```
return createQuery<TransactionDetails>()
    .field("TransactionDateInLong").lessThanOrEq(endDateInLong)
    .field("TransactionDateInLong").greaterThanOrEq(fromDateInLong)
    .field("TYPE").equal("Income")
    .asList();
```

Comment: Understood. Given that the TransactionDetails have a few number of AccountingTransaction (Say max 10), I feel it is better to go by embedding the AccountingTransaction using the @Embedded notation. This way I can save the network calls.